# Cambio de datos de booleanos a enteros en Python

Tags: python

Realizando un proyecto para un curso me encontré con un DataFrame que me arrojaba datos booleanos (Falso y Verdadero), en el momento en que quise realizar un "get_dummies" para cambiar estos valores a 1 y 0, los datos no cambiaron. No he encontrado una forma para cambiar estos datos. ¿Alguien conoce algún método?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `df["algunacolumna"] = df["algunacolumna"].astype(int)`

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias :3

Comment: No hay de que. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask] para que te familiarices con los lineamientos del sitio y de paso obtener tu primer medalla. Normalmente al hacer una pregunta es muy importante que agregues el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema así como un ejemplo de como deseas obtener el resultado, todo debe ir como texto, no como imagen. Normalmente las preguntas que no incluyen lo que se ha intentado o investigado son ignoradas y/o cerradas por la comunidad por no apegarse a los lineamientos del sitio.

Comment: En este caso al ser un error pequeño se pudo resolver por medio de los comentarios, por lo tanto es probable que la pregunta sea cerrada (O también la puedes cerrar tu mismo), si esto sucede no te desanimes, eso sucede con las preguntas que tienen errores sencillos que han sido resueltas en los comentarios o con las preguntas que no cumplen con los lineamientos. Que tengas buen día.